# Websocket client perl vs Node.js

Tags: node.js, perl, tcp

Trying to troubleshoot a Perl Websocket client script.
I've create what I thought was the same functionality in Node.js and it works fine.
The Perl script works just the first time(connects) but the 2nd time it tries it throws an error

> "Unable to connect to.... No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it"
> Blockquote

Why would the node.js client work but not the perl client?
This is the Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $addr = '127.0.0.1';
my $port = '8744';

my $i=0;
while (1) {
    print "Triggering (count: $i)...\n";
    my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $addr,
                             PeerPort => $port,
                             Proto    => 'tcp') or warn("unable to connect to ".$addr.":".$port.": 
     $!\n");
    print $sock "FOO\r\n";
    close $sock;
    sleep 30;
   $i++;
 }
```

and this is the node script

```
(function foo() {
    var net = require('net');
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(8744, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

    client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

    client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
    setTimeout(foo, 30000);
})();
```

Update.
I am appending my entire Server code here. On further debugging I notice that the Perl client immediately causes a SocketException error to be thrown in the server on the first connection at this line
***while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)***

The message is
***Rethrow as IOException. Unable to read data from the transport connection. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine***.

This is probably the root of my problem.

```
public class TCPServer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool isConnection, senddata1, senddata2, valuechanged, valuechanged2;

    public Thread mThread;
    public TcpListener server;
    public TcpClient client;
    public NetworkStream stream;
    byte[] msg1;
    string toSend;
    bool available, selection, endpointChanged, parsedata;
    public String data, prevdata;
    int q = 0;
    int FPS = 0;
    Int32 _port;

    private void Awake()
    {
        UnityThread.initUnityThread();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        isConnection = false;
        senddata1 = false;
        senddata2 = false;
        //print ("StartThread");
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Update1);
        mThread = new Thread(ts);
        mThread.Start();
    }



    void Update1()
    {
        server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 8744.
            Int32 port = 8744;
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();
            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);

                UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                {
                    Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection... ");
                });


                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                if (client != null)
                {
                    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.Log("0 ASSERT TCPServer Connected!");
                    });

                }
                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)    
                {    
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                    {    
                        Debug.Log("1 ASSERT TCPServer Received: data = " + data);

                    });

                    switch (data)
                    {
                        case "TRIGGER":
                            UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                            {
                                Debug.Log("1 ASSERT  TRIGGER RECEIVED");
                            });

                            
                            break;
                        case "Disconnect":
                            goto q;

                        default:
                            prevdata = "RECEIVED_NO_TRIGGER";
                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prevdata);

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);    
                            break;
                    }    
                }
                q:
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }//end while true    

        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SocketException:" + e);
            Debug.LogException( e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a websocket connection, it's a tcp connection. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: *"... but the 2nd time it tries it throws an error ..."* - and the error is exactly what? *"I've create what I thought was the same functionality in Node.js and it works fine."* - The functionality is not the same: different message from the client and the Perl client does not read a response before closing while the nodejs client does.

Comment: the error is the error message that the perl client displays and is in my question.

Further debugging I notice that another difference is that the Perl client immediately causes a SocketException on the 1st connection. I've appended my entire Server code (C#) in my question and indicated the line for the SocketException Error.
Any troubleshooting steps appreciated!

Comment: Essentially I need to find out what changes might be needed in my Perl client OR my TCP server to eliminate these errors.

Comment: If you're sure it's websocket server then Mojolicious user agent FTW.